# Replacing a function with a lambda in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a function that just sets a value of 1 to a struct member variable `length`. In modern C++ this doesn't seem like good code style. Could this be done with a lambda?

```
void setEdgeLengths(Koala::AssocArray <koalaGraph::PEdge, Koala::DijkstraHeap::EdgeLabs<int >> &edgeMap, std::vector<koalaGraph::PEdge>& E) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < E.size(); i++) {
    edgeMap[E[i]].length = 1;
    }
}
```

The reason I am asking is https://shaharmike.com/cpp/lambdas-and-functions/ suggests that the lambda will be faster than an ordinary function.

> Lambdas are also awesome when it comes to performance. Because they are objects rather than pointers they can be inlined very easily by the compiler, much like functors. This means that calling a lambda many times (such as with std::sort or std::copy_if) is much better than using a global function. This is one example of where C++ is actually faster than C.

Comment: I mean, you _can_ do it with a lambda. Just like you can change your car's tires using an excavator. It doesn't mean you did it better... Unless you want to turn the code into `std::for_each` gibberish, just write `for (auto& e : E) edgeMap[e].length = 1;`.

Comment: When you say you want to replace the function with a lambda, are you really asking how to use one of the standard algorithms plus a lambda to replace the fucntion?

Comment: @MaxLanghof good point, but I presume lambda are more efficient?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, which standard algorithm should I use?

Comment: @blacksheep They are not. Don't get me wrong, they are more efficient than many will think, but they don't magically make your trivial loop faster.

Comment: @MaxLanghof so I guess this page is incorrect [https://shaharmike.com/cpp/lambdas-and-functions/] - _Lambdas are also awesome when it comes to performance. Because they are objects rather than pointers they can be inlined very easily by the compiler, much like functors. This means that calling a lambda many times (such as with std::sort or std::copy_if) is much better than using a global function. This is one example of where C++ is actually faster than C._

Comment: There is nothing in your example to indicate that the Lambda would be called "many times"...to refer to all possibilities having not seen your complete code is not even close to being practical.  The responses you have so far are relevant to what you submitted for our speculation

Comment: @blacksheep That comparison is about passing a _function pointer_ to an algorithm (such as C's `qsort`) vs passing a _lambda_ to an algorithm (such as `std::sort`). In the latter case, the compiler can usually optimize better because inlining lambdas is trivial while inlining function pointers is usually not. Your original code has neither function pointers nor library algorithms and thus isn't subject to the statement made in that article.

Comment: Note: a lambda *is* a function.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider the following code optimal (aside from given variable names):

```
void setEdgeLengths(Koala::AssocArray <koalaGraph::PEdge, Koala::DijkstraHeap::EdgeLabs<int >> &edgeMap, std::vector<koalaGraph::PEdge>& E) 
{
    for (const auto& e : E) {
        edgeMap[e].length = 1;
    }
}
```

Style (or omit) the curly braces as you like.

You can put any or all of this into arbitrarily many nested lambdas, but this is no more useful (but likely more harmful, at least in debug builds) than adding more whitespace. What you probably wanted to ask for is this:

```
void setEdgeLengths(Koala::AssocArray <koalaGraph::PEdge, Koala::DijkstraHeap::EdgeLabs<int >> &edgeMap, std::vector<koalaGraph::PEdge>& E) 
{
    std::for_each(E.begin(), E.end(), [&edgeMap](const auto& e) {
        edgeMap[e].length = 1;
    });
}
```

You no longer have a plain loop (which some advocate as good style), but I don't think the code has become any clearer. It also didn't get faster from doing this - if anything, debug performance is likely reduced slightly.

Now, the latter form *does* allow for parallel execution by doing

```
std::for_each(std::execution::parallel, E.begin(), E.end(), [&edgeMap](const auto& e) {
```

but this is only legal if your `edgeMap` properly handles concurrent access. If it was a `std::map`, `operator[]` could potentially insert a new element (which is not thread-safe) so without further assumptions this would not be a legal optimization.

Comment: don't the lambdas in your examples need to capture `edgeMap` in order to access it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply an operation to every element of a container then you can use [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).  Since you want to use every element of `E` to access `edgeMap` you'll use `for_each` on `E` like

```
Koala::AssocArray <koalaGraph::PEdge, Koala::DijkstraHeap::EdgeLabs<int >> edgeMap = /* stuff */;
std::vector<koalaGraph::PEdge> E = /* stuff */;

std::for_each(E.begin(), E.end(),[&](auto const& index){ edgeMap[index].length = 1; });
```

Comment: I think this answer can be improved upon by capturing solely `edgeMap` by reference, as opposed to capturing everything in scope with a plain `&`. That way, it is clear that the `std::for_each` has few side-effects.

Comment: @JoakimThorén `[&]` does not capture *everything* by reference.  In only captures everything it needs by reference.  In my example `[&]` and `[&edgeMap]` produce the exact same code, but `[&]` requires less typing.

Comment: It's true that it does not capture _everything_ by reference, sloppy wording on my part. Using `&` introduces the possibility to accidentally capture something out of everything in scope, which may or may not be problematic.